# Random 'The operation has timed out' errors in JSON-RPC

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I run Bitcoin Core QT and ASP.NET website on the same webserver. My website communicates with Bitcoin Core QT via JSON-RPC. There are hundreds of requests behind the scenes. Sometimes a request finishes with `The operation has timed out` exception. What is wrong with it? This unstable behavior is really annoys me.

My `bitcoin.conf` is:

```
rpcuser = XXXXXXXX
rpcpassword = XXXXXXXX
server=1
rpcallowip=xx.xx.xx.xx
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=xxxx
rpcthreads=1200
```

**UPDATE:** I use heavily edited https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib, which in its turn internally is based on `HttpWebRequest`. `RpcRequestTimeoutInSeconds` is set to 60 seconds. Is it not enough to get balance and account list?

Comment: What kind of RPC calls are you issuing?

Comment: @PieterWuille, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Some operation might take longer then your RPC clients timeout is set to. This could be either due to system workload or due to loading bigger sets of data over RPC (example: a wallet with 100'000 wallet transactions).

Try to debug which commands take long/longer and consider checking your RPC clients http timeout.

Comment: As I see timeout can occur literally in any RPC call. More often in 'ListAccounts', then in 'GetAccountAddress', sometimes even in 'Move' and 'SendRawTransaction'.