# Workaround when the QT wallet is too slow

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've seen in many other QT wallets when you have too many transactions in the same wallet, your QT wallet will be very slow, I mean, when you try to switch from the tab overview to transactions, it will take a long time until the QT wallet responds.

One example is, a normal wallet.dat will have about 2MB, but when the wallet.dat has about 200MB this issue will start to happen.

I haven't tried this on the Bitcoin QT wallet because I can't reproduce this, at least I don't know how I could, but I am pretty sure that will also happen with the Bitcoin QT wallet because all coins basically forked Bitcoin code.

I would like to know if there is one solution for this kind of problem without the need to create a new wallet.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it, it doesn't sound like there is a problem?

Comment: Well it may be, I really would like to reproduce it, but can I?

Comment: It's very hard to provide a solution for a hypothetical situation...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was thinking, maybe there is some solution for this already because at the beginning, I think people used to have wallets with many transactions once the Bitcoin price was too low, then they maybe saw some issue like that and someone made a solution that could still work nowadays.

Comment: @PieterWuille I just found this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45712/random-the-operation-has-timed-out-errors-in-json-rpc Jonas's answer has everything to do with what I mean "due to loading bigger sets of data over RPC (example: a wallet with 100'000 wallet transactions)." would it have a workaround to when that happens?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I am not sure if I got this question right but it sounds pretty strange to me that your wallet.dat file is changing its size. It is only storing your private key (most likely in an encrypted way) and should never change after it is created.

What most clients like bitcoin-qt are doing is to download the blockchain which may increase your wallet folder.

You can easily export the private key from this wallet.dat

[How can I export the private key for an address from the satoshi client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client)

and use it to sign transactions with any other client.

Comment: This is incorrect. The wallet.dat file also stores transactions, labels, timestamps of synchronization, future derived keys, and various things you may want to import. It will almost certainly change size when it is being used.